# La etiqueta Imagen no se muestra ni hace error?

Tags: javascript, json, dom, innerhtml

Básicamente el problema es el siguiente, estoy haciendo una practica de pagina web y por algún motivo la web no me esta cargando una de las imágenes que tengo. El problema es que no me esta indicando cual es la falla y por eso no sé que hacer ya que no me deja subir el codePen Lo subo al git hub que lo voy a dejar también el tema es esta en la Linea del HTML donde esta la ID "marco" para que vean que hay una etiqueta img que llama una imagen esta se ve en la etiqueta pero no en la pagina si saben que puede ser.

```
<html>
<body>

        <div class="participantes">
          <h2>Equipos</h2>

        </div>
      <div class="participantes">
        <div>
            <ul id="listaParticipantes">
              <li><a href="#" data-numero:"0" class="link-equipo"><img height="170px" src="src/220px-EMKlogo.png"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img height="170px" src="src/220px-Penguinslogo.png"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img height="170px" src="src/220px-S2V_Esportslogo.png"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img height="170px" src="src/220px-Splyce_Viperslogo.png"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img height="170px" src="src/220px-Team_Quesologo.png"></a></li>
              <img src="" alt="">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="marco">

        </div>
        </div>

  <script src="js/master.js">

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
  datos=[
    { titulo:"EMK",
      texto:"eMonkeyz nació en noviembre de 2015 de la fusión de Celerius e-Sports , club con una larga historia en la escena nacional, y Bananized , grupo de profesionales con amplia experiencia en el sector de los deportes.",
      jugadores:"../WebRivals/src/Jugadores/Monkey/220px-EMK_DuaLL_2019_Split_2.png"
    }
    //va atener mas datos
  ];

    var marco=document.getElementById("marco");

        function crearEtiquetas(){
          // despues definir clases e ids para las etiquetas
          let titulo_h2=document.createElement("h2");
          titulo_h2.setAttribute("id","titulo");

          let parrafo_p=document.createElement("p");
          parrafo_p.setAttribute("id","texto");

          let jugadores_img=document.createElement("img");
          jugadores_img.setAttribute("id","jugador");
          marco.appendChild(titulo_h2);
          marco.appendChild(parrafo_p);
          marco.appendChild(jugadores_img);

        };

        crearEtiquetas();

        function buscarEquipos(n=0){
          let elementos=datos[n];
          let tituloDOM = document.getElementById("titulo");
          tituloDOM.innerHTML = elementos.titulo;
          let textoDOM = document.getElementById("texto");
          textoDOM.innerHTML = elementos.texto;
          let imagenDOM = document.getElementById("jugador");
          imagenDOM.src = elementos.jugadores;

        };

        buscarEquipos();





GitHub https://github.com/Sertyron/Pratica-webLigaOrange
```

Comment: Edita por favor y agrega el código aquí, lo seleccionas y presionas `ctrl + k` o bien selecciona y presiona el ícono `{}` para que tu código quede formateado

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en al url...

Cambia:

```
jugadores:"../WebRivals/src/Jugadores/Monkey/220px-EMK_DuaLL_2019_Split_2.png"
```

por ...

```
jugadores:"./src/Jugadores/Monkey/220px-EMK_DuaLL_2019_Split_2.png"
```

Y sale la imagen de un chico con la camiseta amarilla pero sale en la parte inferior de la página (necesitas hacer scroll).

Comment: ahi esta gracias